# insertion of divider between JSON lines after extraction of data

Tags: json, parsing, awk, sed, extract

I have a file with 811 JSON lines in it which I need to parse. Now, I'm using the following command to parse the data I'm interested in (`awk` is required due to the fact that the JSON I'm working with doesn't provide the data in a proper array):

```
sed 's/},/},\n/g' 1st_run.json |awk '/"characater"/ { gsub("\"characater\"", "\"char" ++n "\"", $0) } 1'| jq -r '.frames.frame.lps.lp|.characters[]|[.code_ascii,.confidence]|@tsv'
```

This work fine but I get a huge flood of data that is not delimited in any way. How can I at least insert a delimiter after every line in JSON that I  have a somewhat parsable result?

#### input

The JSON input I have is something like:

```
...
{"response":{"container":{"id":"80d996a1-c267-4fa4-b3f8-f61ff9fda198","timestamp":"2018-Jul-10 17:00:50.829709"},"id":"00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"},"frames":{"frame":{"id":"398","timestamp":"2016-Nov-30 12:56:47.900000","lps":{"lp":{"licenseplate":"FRJ724","text":"FRJ724","wtext":"FRJ724","confidence":"67","bkcolor":"16777215","color":"16777215","type":"540122","ntip":"6","cct_country_short":"USA","cct_state_short":"NY","tips":{"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1553","y":"249"},"p":{"x":"1559","y":"249"},"p":{"x":"1559","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1553","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"70","code_ascii":"F","confidence":"88"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1561","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1568","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1568","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1561","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"82","code_ascii":"R","confidence":"96"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1569","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1575","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1576","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1569","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"96"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1585","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1591","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1591","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1585","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"55","code_ascii":"7","confidence":"94"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1593","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1600","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1600","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1593","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"50","code_ascii":"2","confidence":"88"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1602","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1607","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1607","y":"266"},"p":{"x":"1602","y":"266"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"99"}},"ncharacter":"6","characters":{"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1553","y":"249"},"p":{"x":"1559","y":"249"},"p":{"x":"1559","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1553","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"70","code_ascii":"F","confidence":"88"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1561","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1568","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1568","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1561","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"82","code_ascii":"R","confidence":"96"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1569","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1575","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1576","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1569","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"96"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1585","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1591","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1591","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1585","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"55","code_ascii":"7","confidence":"94"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1593","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1600","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1600","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1593","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"50","code_ascii":"2","confidence":"88"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1602","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1607","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1607","y":"266"},"p":{"x":"1602","y":"266"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"99"}},"det_time_us":"776874","poly":{"p":{"x":"1543","y":"237"},"p":{"x":"1618","y":"237"},"p":{"x":"1618","y":"274"},"p":{"x":"1543","y":"274"}}}},"det_time_us":"1883017"}}}
{"response":{"container":{"id":"fa75e8f8-1b44-4f2f-a09b-6fe3b801ca1b","timestamp":"2018-Jul-10 17:00:55.863641"},"id":"00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"},"frames":{"frame":{"id":"399","timestamp":"2016-Nov-30 12:56:48","lps":{"lp":{"licenseplate":"FRJ724","text":"FRJ724","wtext":"FRJ724","confidence":"47","bkcolor":"16777215","color":"16777215","type":"540122","ntip":"6","cct_country_short":"USA","cct_state_short":"NY","tips":{"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1553","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1560","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1560","y":"266"},"p":{"x":"1554","y":"266"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"70","code_ascii":"F","confidence":"96"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1561","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1568","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1568","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1561","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"82","code_ascii":"R","confidence":"98"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1569","y":"247"},"p":{"x":"1576","y":"247"},"p":{"x":"1576","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1569","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"96"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1586","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1592","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1592","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1586","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"55","code_ascii":"7","confidence":"95"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1593","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1600","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1600","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1593","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"50","code_ascii":"2","confidence":"86"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1601","y":"249"},"p":{"x":"1608","y":"249"},"p":{"x":"1608","y":"265"},"p":{"x":"1601","y":"265"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"63"}},"ncharacter":"6","characters":{"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1553","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1560","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1560","y":"266"},"p":{"x":"1554","y":"266"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"70","code_ascii":"F","confidence":"96"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1561","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1568","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1568","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1561","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"82","code_ascii":"R","confidence":"98"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1569","y":"247"},"p":{"x":"1576","y":"247"},"p":{"x":"1576","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1569","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"96"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1586","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1592","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1592","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1586","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"55","code_ascii":"7","confidence":"95"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1593","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1600","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1600","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1593","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"50","code_ascii":"2","confidence":"86"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1601","y":"249"},"p":{"x":"1608","y":"249"},"p":{"x":"1608","y":"265"},"p":{"x":"1601","y":"265"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"63"}},"det_time_us":"600136","poly":{"p":{"x":"1543","y":"238"},"p":{"x":"1618","y":"239"},"p":{"x":"1619","y":"274"},"p":{"x":"1543","y":"273"}}}},"det_time_us":"1495308"}}}
{"response":{"container":{"id":"5c9c773c-a72a-488f-bc49-148dcd6cfa0a","timestamp":"2018-Jul-10 17:01:01.756522"},"id":"00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"},"frames":{"frame":{"id":"400","timestamp":"2016-Nov-30 12:56:48.100000","lps":{"lp":{"licenseplate":"FRJ724","text":"FRJ724","wtext":"FRJ724","confidence":"47","bkcolor":"16777215","color":"16777215","type":"540122","ntip":"6","cct_country_short":"USA","cct_state_short":"NY","tips":{"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1553","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1560","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1560","y":"266"},"p":{"x":"1554","y":"266"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"70","code_ascii":"F","confidence":"96"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1561","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1568","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1568","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1561","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"82","code_ascii":"R","confidence":"98"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1569","y":"247"},"p":{"x":"1576","y":"247"},"p":{"x":"1576","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1569","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"96"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1586","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1592","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1592","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1586","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"55","code_ascii":"7","confidence":"95"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1593","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1600","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1600","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1593","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"50","code_ascii":"2","confidence":"86"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1601","y":"249"},"p":{"x":"1608","y":"249"},"p":{"x":"1608","y":"265"},"p":{"x":"1601","y":"265"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"63"}},"ncharacter":"6","characters":{"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1553","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1560","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1560","y":"266"},"p":{"x":"1554","y":"266"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"70","code_ascii":"F","confidence":"96"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1561","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1568","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1568","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1561","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"82","code_ascii":"R","confidence":"98"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1569","y":"247"},"p":{"x":"1576","y":"247"},"p":{"x":"1576","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1569","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"96"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1586","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1592","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1592","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1586","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"55","code_ascii":"7","confidence":"95"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1593","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1600","y":"248"},"p":{"x":"1600","y":"267"},"p":{"x":"1593","y":"267"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"50","code_ascii":"2","confidence":"86"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1601","y":"249"},"p":{"x":"1608","y":"249"},"p":{"x":"1608","y":"265"},"p":{"x":"1601","y":"265"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"63"}},"det_time_us":"457492","poly":{"p":{"x":"1543","y":"238"},"p":{"x":"1618","y":"239"},"p":{"x":"1619","y":"274"},"p":{"x":"1543","y":"273"}}}},"det_time_us":"1311946"}}}
...
```

#### Output created

```
4       99
9       95
2       94
3       94
9       97
B       96
A       92
B       94
L       76
E       88
B       90
R       95
1       85
4       99
9       87
2       98
3       97
9       98
B       98
A       94
4       91
9       97
2       90
3       92
9       96
B       98
A       99
```

#### Expected output (e.g.)

Divider inserted after each JSON lines, independent of the number of extracted items (per line) - (it es equal to `.ncharacter` in JSON)

```
4       99
9       95
2       94
3       94
9       97
B       96
----------
A       92
B       94
L       76
E       88
B       90
R       95
1       85
4       99
----------
9       87
2       98
3       97
9       98
B       98
A       94
4       91
----------
9       97
2       90
3       92
9       96
B       98
A       99
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the input, especially also of the broken parts?

Comment: @Tomalak I updated the question

Comment: That JSON is not valid for several reasons. In any case you want to insert a delimiter after every line, right? So changing newlines by commas, or adding a comma at the end of the line should be enough, right? Something like `sed 's/$/,/'`

Comment: @Poshi that doesn't really work cause i only getthe output from jq: `$ cat test.json | sed 's/},/},\n/g' |awk '/"characater"/ { gsub("\"characater\"", "\"char" ++n "\"", $0) } 1'| jq -r '.frames.frame.lps.lp|.characters[]|[.code_ascii,.confidence]|@tsv`

Comment: Oh! I thought you were getting a huge flood of input data that could not be parsed. Can you clarify which is the problemmatic input, the expected result and the code you used to try to achieve that? Because the code you wrote generates a tsv output, right?

Comment: @Poshi I apply the above line to parse content that looks like in the initial post. i have 100s of JSON lines that look alike which create a flood of information (~5000 lines)that is hard to parse manually hence I want to insert a line between each parsed JSON string (in the results)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now I see which is the problem

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal? I take it that sed/awk is not your only choice?

Comment: @tomalak no, they're not, i've got access to a full blown Ubuntu distribution and everything that comes with it.

Comment: FYI `characater` isn't a word in English. Maybe you meant `character`? You never need sed when you're using awk since awk can do anything that sed can do.

Comment: @EdMorton I know that `characater` isn't an english word but I get the JSON string delivered from some trhird party. The typo isn't mine. As for`sed` and `awk`, I kind of know but am not super handy with `awk` nor `regexp`s (yet). So I choose what I know works...

Comment: So what I would suggest is to use a pull-parser for JSON. This might be a way of dealing with the invalidity in your input, which appears to be semantic only (duplicate keys) instead of syntactic, so an event-based parser might just do the trick. In any case I would dis-recommend regular expressions for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk to print extra wrapping `[ ]` and `,` for each line.

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "["} END {print "]"} {gsub(/characater/, "char" ++n); print $0 ","}'
```

Comment: would this replace the current awk piece? If so, I get: `parse error: Expected value before ','`

Comment: Do you get that error from the sed, awk, or jq tools or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

I got around it with writing a Python script that can handle the misformatted JSON data. 
The idea is to iterate over each line separately and then break the contents up by substrings to extract `ascii_code` and `confidence` which in the end loos something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def mysplit( str ):
    spltstr = str.split("code_ascii")
    itr = iter(spltstr)
    next(itr)
    for k in itr:
        a = k.split("\"")
        print a[2] + "     " +a[6]

filepath = 'test2.json'
with open(filepath) as fp: 
    line = fp.readline()
    cnt = 1 
    while line:
        print "----------"
        mysplit(line)
        line = fp.readline()
        cnt += 1
```

I think this should pretty much do it for me...