# iterate through multiple json lines

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, loops, dictionary

I've got a file with hundreds of JSON lines in it. I wrote a little python script that will let me extract some data but it only works for one line. I'm now wondering how I can loop through all the lines in my file if there's multiple.
What I have so far is:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

"""with open('1st_run_fixed.json') as f:"""
with open('fixed.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    print "--------------------------------------------";
    """get number of characters"""
    nchar = data["frames"]["frame"]["lps"]["lp"]["ncharacter"];
    print "Got "+nchar+" characters";
    for x in range (1,int(nchar)+1):
        x = str(x);
        print data["frames"]["frame"]["lps"]["lp"]["characters"]["char"+x]["code_ascii"]+"    "+data["frames"]["frame"]["lps"]["lp"]["characters"]["char"+x]["confidence"];
    print "--------------------------------------------";
```

which works for data like:

```
{"response":{"container":{"id":"41d6efcb-24d6-490d-8880-762255519b5f","timestamp":"2018-Jul-11 19:51:06.461665"},
"id":"00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000015"},
"frames":{"frame":{"id":"5583","timestamp":"2016-Nov-30 13:05:27","lps":{"lp":{"licenseplate":"15451BBL","text":"15451BBL","wtext":"15451BBL","confidence":"20","bkcolor":"16777215","color":"16777215","type":"0","ntip":"11","cct_country_short":"","cct_state_short":"","tips":{"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1094","y":"643"},
"p":{"x":"1099","y":"643"},
"p":{"x":"1099","y":"667"},
"p":{"x":"1094","y":"667"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"97"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1103","y":"642"},
"p":{"x":"1113","y":"642"},
"p":{"x":"1112","y":"667"},
"p":{"x":"1102","y":"667"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"89"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1112","y":"640"},
"p":{"x":"1122","y":"640"},
"p":{"x":"1122","y":"666"},
"p":{"x":"1112","y":"666"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"97"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1123","y":"640"},
"p":{"x":"1132","y":"640"},
"p":{"x":"1131","y":"665"},
"p":{"x":"1123","y":"665"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"97"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1134","y":"640"},
"p":{"x":"1139","y":"640"},
"p":{"x":"1139","y":"664"},
"p":{"x":"1133","y":"664"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"77"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1154","y":"639"},
"p":{"x":"1163","y":"639"},
"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"},
"p":{"x":"1153","y":"663"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"97"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1164","y":"638"},
"p":{"x":"1173","y":"638"},
"p":{"x":"1173","y":"663"},
"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"94"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1191","y":"637"},
"p":{"x":"1206","y":"636"},
"p":{"x":"1205","y":"660"},
"p":{"x":"1190","y":"661"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"76","code_ascii":"L","confidence":"34"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1103","y":"655"},
"p":{"x":"1111","y":"655"},
"p":{"x":"1111","y":"667"},
"p":{"x":"1103","y":"667"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"57"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1103","y":"655"},
"p":{"x":"1111","y":"655"},
"p":{"x":"1111","y":"667"},
"p":{"x":"1103","y":"667"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"57"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1176","y":"638"},
"p":{"x":"1185","y":"637"},
"p":{"x":"1184","y":"661"},
"p":{"x":"1175","y":"662"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"7"}},
"ncharacter":"8","characters":{"char1":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1094","y":"643"},
"p":{"x":"1099","y":"643"},
"p":{"x":"1099","y":"667"},
"p":{"x":"1094","y":"667"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"97"},
"char2":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1103","y":"642"},
"p":{"x":"1113","y":"642"},
"p":{"x":"1112","y":"667"},
"p":{"x":"1102","y":"667"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"89"},
"char3":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1112","y":"640"},
"p":{"x":"1122","y":"640"},
"p":{"x":"1122","y":"666"},
"p":{"x":"1112","y":"666"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"97"},
"char4":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1123","y":"640"},
"p":{"x":"1132","y":"640"},
"p":{"x":"1131","y":"665"},
"p":{"x":"1123","y":"665"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"97"},
"char5":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1134","y":"640"},
"p":{"x":"1139","y":"640"},
"p":{"x":"1139","y":"664"},
"p":{"x":"1133","y":"664"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"77"},
"char6":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1154","y":"639"},
"p":{"x":"1163","y":"639"},
"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"},
"p":{"x":"1153","y":"663"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"97"},
"char7":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1164","y":"638"},
"p":{"x":"1173","y":"638"},
"p":{"x":"1173","y":"663"},
"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"94"},
"char8":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1191","y":"637"},
"p":{"x":"1206","y":"636"},
"p":{"x":"1205","y":"660"},
"p":{"x":"1190","y":"661"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"76","code_ascii":"L","confidence":"34"}},
"det_time_us":"1072592","poly":{"p":{"x":"1088","y":"642"},
"p":{"x":"1210","y":"634"},
"p":{"x":"1210","y":"661"},
"p":{"x":"1087","y":"669"}}}},
"det_time_us":"1720812"}}}
```

but I would like to also make it work for data like:

```
{"response":{"container":{"id":"80d996a1-c267-4fa4-b3f8-f61ff9fda198","timestamp":"2018-Jul-10 17:00:50.829709"},
"id":"00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"},
"frames":{"frame":{"id":"398","timestamp":"2016-Nov-30 12:56:47.900000","lps":{"lp":{"licenseplate":"FRJ724","text":"FRJ724","wtext":"FRJ724","confidence":"67","bkcolor":"16777215","color":"16777215","type":"540122","ntip":"6","cct_country_short":"USA","cct_state_short":"NY","tips":{"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1553","y":"249"},
"p":{"x":"1559","y":"249"},
"p":{"x":"1559","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1553","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"70","code_ascii":"F","confidence":"88"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1561","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1568","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1568","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1561","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"82","code_ascii":"R","confidence":"96"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1569","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1575","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1576","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1569","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"96"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1585","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1591","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1591","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1585","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"55","code_ascii":"7","confidence":"94"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1593","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1600","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1600","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1593","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"50","code_ascii":"2","confidence":"88"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1602","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1607","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1607","y":"266"},
"p":{"x":"1602","y":"266"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"99"}},
"ncharacter":"6","characters":{"char1":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1553","y":"249"},
"p":{"x":"1559","y":"249"},
"p":{"x":"1559","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1553","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"70","code_ascii":"F","confidence":"88"},
"char2":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1561","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1568","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1568","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1561","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"82","code_ascii":"R","confidence":"96"},
"char3":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1569","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1575","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1576","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1569","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"96"},
"char4":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1585","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1591","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1591","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1585","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"55","code_ascii":"7","confidence":"94"},
"char5":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1593","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1600","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1600","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1593","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"50","code_ascii":"2","confidence":"88"},
"char6":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1602","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1607","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1607","y":"266"},
"p":{"x":"1602","y":"266"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"99"}},
"det_time_us":"776874","poly":{"p":{"x":"1543","y":"237"},
"p":{"x":"1618","y":"237"},
"p":{"x":"1618","y":"274"},
"p":{"x":"1543","y":"274"}}}},
"det_time_us":"1883017"}}}
{"response":{"container":{"id":"fa75e8f8-1b44-4f2f-a09b-6fe3b801ca1b","timestamp":"2018-Jul-10 17:00:55.863641"},
"id":"00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"},
"frames":{"frame":{"id":"399","timestamp":"2016-Nov-30 12:56:48","lps":{"lp":{"licenseplate":"FRJ724","text":"FRJ724","wtext":"FRJ724","confidence":"47","bkcolor":"16777215","color":"16777215","type":"540122","ntip":"6","cct_country_short":"USA","cct_state_short":"NY","tips":{"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1553","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1560","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1560","y":"266"},
"p":{"x":"1554","y":"266"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"70","code_ascii":"F","confidence":"96"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1561","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1568","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1568","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1561","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"82","code_ascii":"R","confidence":"98"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1569","y":"247"},
"p":{"x":"1576","y":"247"},
"p":{"x":"1576","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1569","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"96"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1586","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1592","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1592","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1586","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"55","code_ascii":"7","confidence":"95"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1593","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1600","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1600","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1593","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"50","code_ascii":"2","confidence":"86"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1601","y":"249"},
"p":{"x":"1608","y":"249"},
"p":{"x":"1608","y":"265"},
"p":{"x":"1601","y":"265"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"63"}},
"ncharacter":"6","characters":{"char7":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1553","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1560","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1560","y":"266"},
"p":{"x":"1554","y":"266"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"70","code_ascii":"F","confidence":"96"},
"char8":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1561","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1568","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1568","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1561","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"82","code_ascii":"R","confidence":"98"},
"char9":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1569","y":"247"},
"p":{"x":"1576","y":"247"},
"p":{"x":"1576","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1569","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"96"},
"char10":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1586","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1592","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1592","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1586","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"55","code_ascii":"7","confidence":"95"},
"char11":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1593","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1600","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1600","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1593","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"50","code_ascii":"2","confidence":"86"},
"char12":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1601","y":"249"},
"p":{"x":"1608","y":"249"},
"p":{"x":"1608","y":"265"},
"p":{"x":"1601","y":"265"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"63"}},
"det_time_us":"600136","poly":{"p":{"x":"1543","y":"238"},
"p":{"x":"1618","y":"239"},
"p":{"x":"1619","y":"274"},
"p":{"x":"1543","y":"273"}}}},
"det_time_us":"1495308"}}}
{"response":{"container":{"id":"5c9c773c-a72a-488f-bc49-148dcd6cfa0a","timestamp":"2018-Jul-10 17:01:01.756522"},
"id":"00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"},
"frames":{"frame":{"id":"400","timestamp":"2016-Nov-30 12:56:48.100000","lps":{"lp":{"licenseplate":"FRJ724","text":"FRJ724","wtext":"FRJ724","confidence":"47","bkcolor":"16777215","color":"16777215","type":"540122","ntip":"6","cct_country_short":"USA","cct_state_short":"NY","tips":{"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1553","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1560","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1560","y":"266"},
"p":{"x":"1554","y":"266"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"70","code_ascii":"F","confidence":"96"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1561","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1568","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1568","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1561","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"82","code_ascii":"R","confidence":"98"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1569","y":"247"},
"p":{"x":"1576","y":"247"},
"p":{"x":"1576","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1569","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"96"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1586","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1592","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1592","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1586","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"55","code_ascii":"7","confidence":"95"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1593","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1600","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1600","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1593","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"50","code_ascii":"2","confidence":"86"},
"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1601","y":"249"},
"p":{"x":"1608","y":"249"},
"p":{"x":"1608","y":"265"},
"p":{"x":"1601","y":"265"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"63"}},
"ncharacter":"6","characters":{"char13":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1553","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1560","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1560","y":"266"},
"p":{"x":"1554","y":"266"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"70","code_ascii":"F","confidence":"96"},
"char14":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1561","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1568","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1568","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1561","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"82","code_ascii":"R","confidence":"98"},
"char15":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1569","y":"247"},
"p":{"x":"1576","y":"247"},
"p":{"x":"1576","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1569","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"96"},
"char16":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1586","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1592","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1592","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1586","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"55","code_ascii":"7","confidence":"95"},
"char17":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1593","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1600","y":"248"},
"p":{"x":"1600","y":"267"},
"p":{"x":"1593","y":"267"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"50","code_ascii":"2","confidence":"86"},
"char18":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1601","y":"249"},
"p":{"x":"1608","y":"249"},
"p":{"x":"1608","y":"265"},
"p":{"x":"1601","y":"265"}},
"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"63"}},
"det_time_us":"457492","poly":{"p":{"x":"1543","y":"238"},
"p":{"x":"1618","y":"239"},
"p":{"x":"1619","y":"274"},
"p":{"x":"1543","y":"273"}}}},
"det_time_us":"1311946"}}}
```

How can I get this done?

My script currently returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 68 column 1 - line 202 column 1 (char 3182 - 9548)

shell returned 1
```

When i run the large file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insertion of divider between JSON lines after extraction of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332843/insertion-of-divider-between-json-lines-after-extraction-of-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've got a file with hundreds of JSON lines in it.

No you don't, and that's the problem.

---

Hundreds of JSON texts is not a valid JSON file. A valid JSON file is just one text. Which is why `json.load` is returning an error.

---

Hundreds of JSON texts that each fit on exactly one line with newlines in between them *is* a valid file in other formats like JSONlines or NDJ. It's still not a valid JSON file, so you can't use `json.load`, but you could use a JSONlines or NDJ library, or just parse it like this:

```
with open('fixed.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
        # do stuff
```

For writing a JSONlines file, again, you can use a JSONlines library, or you can just make sure that each JSON text has no embedded newlines—which actually happens by default, if you don't specify non-default `ensure_ascii` or `indent` parameters—and just write out `json.dumps(data) + "\n"` for each value.

---

But hundreds of JSON texts that each take up multiple lines isn't a valid anything file.

This is actually [explained in the `json` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps):

> Note Unlike `pickle` and `marshal`, JSON is not a framed protocol, so trying to serialize multiple objects with repeated calls to `dump()` using the same *fp* will result in an invalid JSON file.

What "not a framed protocol" means is basically that the format would be ambiguous. For example, if you did a `json.dump(2, f)`, and then a `json.dump(3, f)`, what you'd get in your file is `23`. Which is the same thing you get from `json.dump(23, f)`.

---

If you can fix your file to be something valid, like JSONlines, that's the easy solution.

---

If you can't…

Well, pre-standardization, there was a concept of "JSON document", which meant basically a JSON text that's either an Array or Object. And a stream of JSON documents is *not* ambiguous.

Since this isn't a standard format, you're probably not going to find a parser for it, so you'll have to write one yourself.

One way you can do that is by using the [`raw_decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode) method in the `json` module. This will try to decode a JSON text, possibly with extra stuff after it, and also return the index to that extra stuff. Which, in your case, is the next JSON document.

Since hundreds of objects of that size isn't too big, it's probably simpler to just read the whole file into memory and then parse it, so we don't have to worry about buffering:

```
with open('fixed.json') as f:
    contents = f.read()
decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
while contents:
    data, idx = decoder.raw_decode(contents)
    do_stuff(data)
    contents = contents[idx:].lstrip()
```

Remember that this will only work if your file is a stream of JSON documents—that is, the top-level values are always Array or Object. Also, if you're editing these files by hand, unlike JSONlines, which can skip one bad text and continue to parse the rest, there's now way to recover from an error here, because you have no idea where the next document starts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but your suggestion `json.loads(line)` suggestion doesn't seem to work :(, I get an error

Comment: @cerr First, the answer does not suggest that, it explains why that will not work unless you fix your data. Second, “I get an error” is not something that anyone can debug you for. in this case, I can guess what error you get, because I already know why that code won’t work for your data, but in general, if you want people to help you, you need to give them enough information to help.

Comment: I understand but I literally get `Traceback (most recent call last):\nFile "read.py", line 9, in <module>\ndata= json.loads(line)`then `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads\nreturn _default_decoder.decode(s)`

Comment: the issue is: I have a log file with a whole bunch of information and some JSON lines interleaved. I then grepped the JSON lines and put them into a single file to extract data I'm interested in...

Comment: @cerr Showing me part of a traceback that doesn't even contain the error type or message isn't very helpful, but it doesn't matter. The first line of your file is not a JSON text. So if you call `json.loads(line)` on it, you're going to get a `JSONDecodeError`. What you have is not a JSONlines file, any more than it's a JSON file, so trying to decode it as one is going to fail. I don't know how else to explain that.

Comment: i don't see `JSONDecodeError` in the traceback anywhere. So are you suggesting I remove all newlines from my file? I can do that with a simple `sed`

Comment: @cerr Since you didn't show me the error message, I can only guess what's there. And no, I'm not suggesting you remove all newlines in the file, I'm suggesting you remove all newlines within each JSON text (including escaping any that are inside strings) but leave the newlines between them. Or, if you can't do that, read the rest of the answer and, if all of your top-level texts as Arrays or Objects, try what it suggests instead of trying code that is guaranteed to fail.